# Restful URL custom authentication failing in java

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, restful-url

This code is for getting the text from some URL which is having custom authentication as specified below.Tried with even **ajax** and **Jquery** as dataType:"jsonp" but it is also showing **401 error**.

```
  URL u;
  HttpURLConnection con;
  InputStream is = null;
  DataInputStream dis;
  String s;
  try {
   // u = new URL("http://q.addthis.com/feeds/1.0/trending.json?pubid=atblog");
      u = new URL("http://m2mportal.connectm.com/EMS/rest/device");
     is = u.openStream(); 

      con=(HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
      con.connect();
      con.setDoOutput(true);
      con.setRequestMethod("GET");
      con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
      con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","authenticate\":{\"userName\":\"admin01\",\"password\":\"admin01$\",\"appId\":\"123\"}");  

      con.setRequestProperty("userName","admin01");
      con.setRequestProperty("password","admin01$");
      con.setRequestProperty("appId","123");          
     dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
     while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) 
     {
        System.out.println(s);
     }
  } 
  catch (MalformedURLException mue) 
  {

     System.out.println("Ouch - a MalformedURLException happened.");
     mue.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);

  } 
  catch (IOException ioe) 
  {
     System.out.println("Oops- an IOException happened.");
     ioe.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);
  } 
  catch(IllegalStateException ise)
  {
      System.out.println("In IllegalState Exception........");
      ise.printStackTrace();
  }
```

---

When tried to authenticate against a url which is having some custom authentication as shown in the code it is returning **401 error**

```
Oops- an IOException happened.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: some url
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at com.techm.JavaGetUrl.main(JavaGetUrl.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem here is Authorization property that you passed is not encoded.

You need to pass it to Base64 encoder so that  http Authorization mechanism will use it.

**Base64 encoding** is commonly used when there is a need to encode / decode binary data stored and transferred over network.

Add encoding to your code . change your code to :

you need to use

> Base64.encodeToString()

to perform encoding.

Following link will help you more:
http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/08/how-to-encode-and-decode-in-base64-using-java